# setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in nanohttpd

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, nanohttpd

I have a cordova application that uses nanoHttpd to serve files. How do i set Access-Control-Allow_origin for the files served by nanoHttpd. I went through source code of the server, but I was not able to find how to set this header.

Note: The xmlhttp request is done from child browser plugin

Comment: How are you calling to server through ajax ?

Comment: The file has to be loaded by [pdfjs](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and pdfjs internally uses XmlHttp

Comment: so you just need to white list the remote server . that's all

Comment: do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the white listing of the server

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: anish, this we give in phonegap. This works perfectly if the webview is cordova webview. But I forgot to mention that this xmlhttp request is done from child browser plugin for cordova